# psql: Connection refused. pqAdmin: the database system is starting up

Tags: postgresql, psql

- Windows Server 2012
- Postgres 9.6

I made a replication with the master server. On the slave server service postgres is running, but in log files slave's server "`FATAL:  the database system is starting up`" message will continue.

when I try from the command line run the command

```
psql.exe -U postgres`
```

writes the following error:

> psql: ... Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) ...

My postgresql.conf configuration is on the slave server:

```
listen_addresses = 'ip slave adress'
hot_standby = on
wal_receiver_status_interval = 0
hot_standby_feedback = on
```

My recovery.conf configuration is on the slave server:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=ip master server port=5432 user=postgres' 
primary_slot_name = 'slot_1'
trigger_file = 'D:\Postgres Data\Start_master'
```

Could you please to fix this issue? I don't understand what could be the problem.
I've made shutdown the server, the problem is not resolved.

Comment: If you have a look at the logs on the slave, is it restoring WAL from the archive?  If not, then you may have missed to set up either WAL archiving or a replication slot.

Comment: Could you please explain more detail, what do you mean? files in 'pg_xlog' transferred to the archive_status folder with prefix 'done'